# Playing card problem solution verification

Tags: probability

I have the following simple playing card problem and I would like someone to verify that the solution is correct :)

Problem: You have four playing cards, two black cards and two red cards. You turn the cards over so that you can't see the the colour of the card. Now you pick two cards wihout replacement. What is the probability that the cards have same color?

Here is my attempted solution (I denote $C1$ being the first card and $C2$ second card and black and red as $B$ and $R$):

$$P(\text{Both cards same color}) = P(C1 = R \;\;\cap\;\; C2 = R ) + P(C1 = B \;\;\cap\;\; C2 = B ) = P(C1 = R)P(C2=R\;|\;C1=R) + P(C1 = B)P(C2=B\;|\;C1=B) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Looks good to me. The other way you could see this -- drawing your first card doesn't matter; when you draw your second card, you need to pick the same colour as your first card, which has a probability of $1/3$.

Comment: Not a problem! Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution works.

Yet another approach coming to the same answer is that there are ${4 \choose 2}=6$ equally likely ways of choosing two cards without replacement from four.  Of these six possibilities, two are pairs of the same colour, namely the black pair or the red pair.  So the answer is $\dfrac{2}{6}= \dfrac{1}{3}$, the same as yours.